# Setting a scheduled task inside an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, scheduled-tasks

I have an activity (MapActivity actually) that has a linearLayout with a mapView and a textView, for displaying current speed, among other things. The thing is that I would like the textView to be updated every 0.5 seconds, for example.

I know this can be done with a service (at least that is how I learnt to do it), but I was wondering if it is possible to do so using a Timer inside the MapActivity itself. I tried this approach:

```
onCreate{
...
    updateTimer = new Timer(); 
    updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(doRefresh, 0, updateInterval);
   }

   private Timer updateTimer;
   private TimerTask doRefresh = new TimerTask()
   {
    public void run()
    {
       updateData();
    }
   };

    private void updateData()
    {
       //update the textView with the data
    }
   private int updateInterval = 500;
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
04-10 22:24:56.529: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9434): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Then, is it possible to do what I'm trying in an easy way, without using a service class?

Thank you and regards,
=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `postDelayed()` on some widget, supplying a `Runnable` and `500` as the delay. The `Runnable` should do whatever work you want done, then call `postDelayed()` again with itself as the `Runnable` and `500` as the delay.

This avoids background threads and services, which are not needed for simple timing events in an activity.